# Enforce trailing slash in Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relative-path, rails-routing, trailing-slash

Adding a trailing slash in your links is easy enough with {:trailing_slash => true}, but this doesn't account for if a user types in a non-slashed url.  Is there a way to enforce trailing slashes via redirects in the router?

```
get "/:controller/:id" => redirect{|params| "/#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:id]}/" }
```

The above leads to a circular loop.

Why?

a relative link of "./subclass" on

```
/parent/1
```

is much different than

```
/parent/1/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the config/application.rb file, add

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

in the Application class